# this dentro de um construtor, o que faz?

Tags: java

boas , alguém me pode dizer o que é que este this faz ?

```
public Tempo (){
    this(0,0,0);
} 
public Tempo (int h){

    this(h,0,0);
}
public Tempo ( int h,int m){

    this (h,m,0);
}
public Tempo (int h,int m , int s){
    SetTime(h,m,s);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A construção `this` dentro do construtor serve para chamar outro construtor.

Ou seja `this(0,0,0);` vai chamar o construtor

```
public Tempo (int h,int m , int s){
    SetTime(h,m,s);
}
```

Ela não pode ser usada num método convencional e tem que ser obrigatoriamente a primeira instrução dentro do construtor, isto é, se pretender usá-la. É só uma forma de manter a lógica de inicialização do objeto em apenas um dos construtores.

Comment: Ao chamar o construtor significa que vai executar o conteúdo desse construtor ,ou seja o método setTime ?

Comment: Perfeito, Bruno.
Só para complementar, o que vai definir qual construtor que será chamado, são os tipos e a quantidade de parâmetros passada no método this().

Comment: @PedroGouveia Sim Pedro, ele vai chamar o `setTime`